# Control Flow - if condition in Julia

Tags: if-statement, julia

I'm using Julia to solve an integer program. My variables are of the form `z[i,j], i in N and j in N` and `N=10`and `z[i,j]` is a binary variable.

In the first half of the program, I have a set of solutions for which `z[1,2]= 1` and `z[1,3]=1` and all other variables are zero. Now, I need to pass these values to another set S in such a way that `S={1,2,3}`. I tried to code it in Julia, but I couldn't get it in the right way. The following is the what I've tried.Here, z_value is the way that I declare my variables `z[i,j]`.   Can someone please help me to make it correct?

```
for i in N
 for j in N 
   z_value = Pair(i,j)
   if z_value == 1;
     push!(S, Pair(i,j))
     print(S)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: What is the problem? I do see some issues: `z_value == 1` will always return false, as 1 is not a Pair. And you didn't allocate S before pushing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Michael and Stefan, I got required set S by rearranging the code as

```
    for i in N
    for j in N
        if getvalue(z[i,j]) == 1
           push!(S, i) 
           push!(S, j)
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks for your effort!!